# Ionic4: Phonegap-nfc: where is the content?

Tags: ionic4

VERSION: Ionic 4
Plugin: phonegap-nfc

Hi everyone!

I'm trying to use this plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc) and following the instructions, I should be able to read a message sent from another NFC device. The event is fired and I know something is sent, but I'm not able to understand what and where the message is stored.

This is the code:

*home.page.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Ndef, NFC} from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx';
import {AlertController} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private nfc: NFC, private ndef: Ndef, private alertController: AlertController) { }

  readNFC() {
    this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
      this.presentAlert('ok');
    }, (err) => {
      this.presentAlert('ko' + err);
    }).subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

      this.presentAlert('Il messaggio contiene' + event.tag + ' ' + this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));
    });

  }


  writeNFC() {
    this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
      console.log('successfully attached ndef listener');
      const message = this.ndef.textRecord('Hello world');
      this.nfc.share([message]).then(
          value => {
            this.presentAlert('ok');
          }
      ).catch(
          reason => {
            this.presentAlert('ko');
          }
      );
    }, (err) => {
      this.presentAlert('ko' + err);
    });

  }


  async presentAlert(mess) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'attenzione',
      message: mess,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {Ndef, NFC} from '@ionic-native/nfc/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
      NFC,
      Ndef
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is the stringify obtained by printing the content of event:

```
{"isTrusted":false,"tag":{"id":[0],"techTypes":["android.nfc.tech.Ndef"],"type":"android.ndef.unknown","maxSize":0,"isWritable":false,"ndefMessage":[{"tnf":1,"type":[85],"id":[],"payload":[3,112,108,97,121,46,103,111,111,103,108,101,46,99,111,109,47,115,116,111,114,101,47,97,112,112,115,47,100,101,116,97,105,108,115,63,105,100,61,99,111,109,46,119,97,107,100,101,118,46,119,100,110,102,99,38,102,101,97,116,117,114,101,61,98,101,97,109]},{"tnf":4,"type":[97,110,100,114,111,105,100,46,99,111,109,58,112,107,103],"id":[],"payload":[99,111,109,46,119,97,107,100,101,118,46,119,100,110,102,99]}],"canMakeReadOnly":false}}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is at

> ndefMessage[0].payload

you need to use

> nfc.bytesToString()

the payload to convert to string